# php writing to file permissions issue

Tags: php, file, permissions, fopen

When php-script is trying to write to a file:

```
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 eugene_val eugene_val  8033 Sep 10 10:47 ajax_EN.json
```

I get an error:

```
fopen(ajax_EN.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I wonder what could be an appropriate solution to it taking security into consideration.
The options I could think of are:

1) chown this file to apache user and chmod it to 700

2) add apache to a group of the file-owner

3) use suPHP and likes(which I would not like to because of the performance hit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permissions of the path for this file also matter. Even if you chmod 777 the file, if the user trying to read it doesn't have read permissions for the path, they still won't be able to read the file.

Comment: I did not advise that he use 777.  Please read my answer again.

Comment: I don't see why I need to edit my answer.  I did not advise that anyone use 777.  I said _even if you did_ use it, it wouldn't matter if the path permissions aren't correct.

Comment: you misunderstand, edit your answer is allowed the down vote to be removed

Comment: Apologies, I am still new to this.

Answer (score 3):

A better choice is to change the file's group to the Apache user group, and set the file to be group-writable:

```
$ chgrp <apache_group> ajax_EN.json
$ chmod g+w ajax_EN.json
```

Comment: Thank You. Still I'm not sure about the risks of changing the file's group to apache...

Comment: If you are on a shared server, or if other people's scripts run via Apache, they can also edit your file (if they know it exists). If you need to modify the file via a web script, there is no other choice. If you can modify the file via some other process (cron, for example), you can avoid changing the group in this manner.